# Issue with ng-show in angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I cannot show an error message when validation the first field in this example.

Only the second field show up the message.
Could you tell me what is wrong in my code?

http://plnkr.co/edit/OXtrm9skUUe1D6e8F8gw?p=preview

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

    app.directive('gaTime', function () {
        var EMAIL_REGX = /^(?:2[0-3]|[01][0-9]):[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]$/;
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            scope: {
                timeInfo: '=info' // Unique to directive scope
            },
            template: '<input type="text" name="operativeToTime" data-ng-model="timeInfo" data-ng-required="false" data-ng-pattern="/^(?:2[0-3]|[01][0-9]):[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]$/">'
        };
    });

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
    // Default values
    $scope.operativeFromTime = '00:00:00';
    $scope.operativeToTime = '23:59:59';
});


  <form name="addDeviceForm" data-ng-submit="submitForm(addDeviceForm.$valid)" novalidate>
            <data-ga-time name="operativeFromTime" info="operativeFromTime"></data-ga-time>
            <span data-ng-show="addDeviceForm.operativeFromTime.$invalid">+++ INVALID FROM.</span>
            <br>

            <data-ga-time name="operativeToTime" info="operativeToTime"></data-ga-time>
            <span data-ng-show="addDeviceForm.operativeToTime.$invalid">+++ INVALID TO.</span>
  </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that `name` is hard-coded in the directive's template.

To fix this, use a template function to add the `name` attribute to your template string dynamically:

```
template: function(tElem, tAttrs){

    return '<input type="text" name="' + tAttrs.name +
           '" data-ng-model="timeInfo" data-ng-required="false" 
            data-ng-pattern="/^(?:2[0-3]|[01][0-9]):[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]$/">';
}
```

[Demo Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/6CDq9kryQqgt6X0kizrr?p=preview)

Note: the `name` attribute is required for [form validation in Angular](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms#binding-to-form-and-control-state)

Answer (score 1):

Please see here http://plnkr.co/edit/UeX6eAyjDPmqLagRQZmy?p=preview
in your template you've got unnecessarily `name="operativeToTime"`

```
 app.directive('gaTime', function () {
        var EMAIL_REGX = /^(?:2[0-3]|[01][0-9]):[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]$/;
        return {
            restrict: 'E',
            replace: 'true',
            scope: {
                timeInfo: '=info' ,// Unique to directive scope

            },
            template: '<input type="text"  data-ng-model="timeInfo" data-ng-required="false" data-ng-pattern="/^(?:2[0-3]|[01][0-9]):[0-5][0-9]:[0-5][0-9]$/">'
        };
    });
```

Comment: thanks for sharing but I need the name attribute so it can be use in a label tag for (the template add a input tag).

Comment: please see html source the name attribute is still there